# Why does the monotone convergence theorem not apply on Riemann integrals?

Tags: measure-theory, examples-counterexamples, riemann-integration

I had just learned in measure theory class about the monotone convergence theorem in this version:

For every monotonically increasing sequence of functions $f_n$ from measurable space $X$ to $[0, \infty]$,
$$
\text{if}\quad
\lim_{n\to \infty}f_n = f,
\quad\text{then}\quad
\lim_{n\to \infty}\int f_n \, \mathrm{d}\mu = \int f \,\mathrm{d}\mu
.
$$

I tried to find out why this theorem apply only for a Lebesgue integral, but I didn't find a counter example for Riemann integrals, so I would appreciate your help.

(I guess that $f$ might not be integrable in some cases, but I want a concrete example.)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Riemann integrable functions (on a compact interval) are also Lebesgue integrable and the two integrals coincide. So the theorem is surely valid for Riemann integrals also.

However the  pointwise increasing limit of a sequence of Riemann integrable functions need not be Riemann integrable. Let $(r_n)$ be an ennumeration of the rationals in $[0,1]$, and let $f_n$ be as follows:

$$f_n(x) =
\begin{cases}
1  & \text{if $x \in \{ r_0, r_1, \dots, r_{n-1} \}$} \\
0  & \text{if $x \in \{ r_n, r_{n+1}, \dots \}$} \\
0  & \text{if $x$ is irrational} \\
\end{cases}$$

Then the limit function is nowhere continuous, hence not Riemann integrable.

Comment: I think the problem is more the other way round. If you start with a sequence of Riemann integrable functions $(f_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ that converges point-wise to $f$. Is $f$ again Riemann integrable? And what about the szenario where you are not on a compact interval?

Comment: @NathanaelSkrepek Thank you. I have given a counter-example for the domain $[0,1]$.

Answer (score 17):

Here is a version of the Monotone convergence theorem for Riemann integrals that can be proved without referring to measure theory:

> **Theorem**. Let $\{f_n\}$ be a nondecreasing sequence of Riemann integrable functions on $[a,b]$ converging pointwise to a Riemann integrable function $f$ on $[a,b]$. Then
>   $$
> \lim_{n\to \infty}\int_a^b f_n(x)\,dx=\int_a^b f(x)\,dx.
> $$

An elementary proof is given in this [paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/233658851_Monotone_Convergence_Theorem_for_the_Riemann_Integral).

Comment: thanks! so I guess that I'm looking for an concrete example of monotonic series of positive riemann integrable functions whose limit is not riemann integrable.

Comment: @AmitKeinan I have given such an example in my answer.

Comment: Look at this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/612098/an-example-of-a-sequence-of-riemann-integrable-functions-f-n-that-converges).

Answer (score 0):

I spent about two weeks working on an elementary proof of this problem earlier this year.

There is an elementary proof of something slightly stronger:
Let $f_n$ tend pointwise to $0$ on $[0,1]$, with $f_n$ Riemann integrable, and for all $x$ sup $|f_n(x)| \leq 1$. (This has the obvious generalisation to an arbitrary interval, with convergence pointwise to a Riemann integrable function and $f_n$ uniformly bounded).

I would be happy to write up my proof after my exams are finished this summer :)

This is a slightly harder version of a problem given on this problem set for second year undergraduates at the university of cambridge, although that also allows the assumption that the $f_n$ are continuous.