# Doubt about counterexample of the Monotone convergence theorem and Riemann integral

Tags: integration, lebesgue-integral, riemann-integration

In this question [Why does the monotone convergence theorem not apply on Riemann integrals?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3455580/why-does-the-monotone-convergence-theorem-not-apply-on-riemann-integrals) there is the typical counterexample showing that the monotone convergence theorem does not hold for Riemann integrals. My question is: Why is $f_n(x)$ Riemann integrable for all $n$?

From the Lebesgue criterion, a function is Riemann integrable if it is bounded and the set of discontinuites has Lebesgue measure $0$. The boundedness is clear, however, I thought that $f_n(x)$ would be discontinuous for all $x \in [0,r_{n-1}]$ (assuming the enumeration of the rationals $r_1,r_2,...$ is ordered from lowest to highest) since if $x$ is an irrational number in $[0,r_{n-1}]$ I can find a sequence $x_k$, $k = 1,2,...$ in $[0,r_{n-1}]$ of rational numbers such that $f_n(x_k) = 1$ for all $k$ and $f_n(x) = 0$. And the reverse argument if $x \in [0,r_{n-1}]$ is rational. Finally the Lebesgue measure of $[0,r_{n-1}]$ is $r_{n-1}$ which is not $0$.

Also the upper Riemann sums should be strictly greater than zero since for some interval $[x_i, x_{i+1}]$ it will happen that $\sup_{x \in [x_i, x_{i+1}]} f_n(x) = 1$ (since rationals are dense in the reals) while the lower Riemann sum will always be zero.

What am I missing in these arguments?

Comment: If you modify a Riemann-integrable function in one point (and therefore in finitely many points) - it remains Riemann-integrable. So, we have obtained $f_n(x)$ by taking the zero function and just modifying it at $r_0, r_1, \ldots , r_{n-1}$ to become $1$ (instead of $0$) - it  stays Riemann-integrable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The existing comments and answers tend to explain why the result is true, with less that I can see on where you error is.

It's not true that $f_n$ is discontinuous at every rational in $[0,r_n]$. In fact $f_n$ is continuous everywhere except at $r_1,\dots,r_n$. Your $f_n(x_k)=1$  only holds when $k\le n$, so you can't let $k\to\infty$ (with $n$ fixed) the way you do.

Answer (score 1):

For each fixed $n$ the function $f_n$ is $0$ except at a finite number of points $r_0,r_1,..,r_{n-1}$. Such a function is clearly continuous at all points except this finite number, i.e. $r_0,r_1,..,r_{n-1}$. [You get $n$ open intervals when you remove these points from the domain and $f_n$ is continuous on each of these open intervals].

Comment: but since rationals are dense in the reals any open interval will contain rational numbers, hence there you cannot take $n$ open intervals without any rational numbers, no?

Comment: I guess what i am not seeing is that in $[0,r_{n-1}]$ the set of rationals is countable (infintely), however the counterexample refers to a finite enumeration and hence enumerates just some rationals leaving space for open intervals without any rationals

Comment: You are forgetting that $f_n$ does not involve all rationals number at all. Its definition involves only $n$ rational numbers. Remember that you are **fixing** $n$. @JRT